# What's the time complexity of constructing a Counter object from an iterable in Python?

Tags: python, collections, time-complexity, counter, complexity-theory

```
cnt = Counter ("Hello")
cnt = Counter ([1,2,3,3,3])
```

I think the time complexities for the code above are O(N), where N is the length of each collection.

I didn't find the exact time complexity of Counter() object [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). I really appreciate it if someone can confirm my guess.

Comment: @wim Why is that? Give answer to this question with explanation or documentation proof link, please.

Answer (score 1):

As the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L483) and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) show, `Counter` is just a subclass of `dict`, optimized for counting objects. Constructing it from an iterable has the time complexity of `O(n)`, since it iterates all items and updates counters for each item in `O(1)` constant time.

The [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of other `dict` operations will also hold for `Counter`.